# Communication between podman containers without root

Tags: docker, fedora, podman

I am trying to deploy a web app with two podman containers. One is running gunicorn and the other runs a web server as a reverse proxy.

However, the communication between the containers is only successfull if I run them on the host with root. Is there a way around this?

Here is an example without root (which returns an empty IP Address):

```
$ podman run -dt --name test --rm -p 8000:8000 python:3.9 python -m http.server
$ podman container inspect test | grep IPAddress
            "IPAddress": "",
```

With root, it is possible to do:

```
$ sudo podman run -dt --name test --rm -p 8000:8000 python:3.9 python -m http.server
$ sudo podman container inspect test | grep IPAddress
           "IPAddress": "10.88.0.11",
                    "IPAddress": "10.88.0.11",
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM caddy:2
COPY Caddyfile /etc/caddy/Caddyfile
$ cat Caddyfile
:8001 {
    reverse_proxy * 10.88.0.11:8000
}
$ sudo podman build . -t revproxy
$ sudo podman run -dt --rm -p 8001:8001 revproxy
```

and the proxy is working successfully on port 8001.

Comment: Apparently, they have to be in the same pod or network to communicate (unless complete access to the host network is permitted).

Comment: Good to hear you have found a solution. Could you add it as an answer?

Comment: @ErikSjölund of course. I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two containers have to be in the same pod or the same network.

Using a pod, it is possible to do the following:

```
$ podman pod create -n test
$ podman run --rm --pod test python:3 python3 -m http.server
```

and in another shell:

```
$ podman run --rm --pod test python:3 curl localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless if you are running your podman containers rootful or rootless you can always reach the host (and therefore other containers) using `host.containers.internal`.

Let's say we are running these containers in this way:

```
$ sudo podman run -d --name httpd -p 8080:80 docker.io/httpd
$ podman run -d --name httpd -p 8888:80 docker.io/httpd
```

If we then start an interactive bash using an ubuntu image like any of the below:

```
$ podman run -it ubuntu bash
$ sudo podman -it ubuntu bash
```

We can curl to both httpd (Apache2) containers like this:

```
$ curl host.containers.internal:8080
$ curl host.containers.internal:8888
```

The magic is in the containers `/etc/hosts` file which has an entry like this (Rootless):

```
172.17.23.45  host.containers.internal
```

or if you are running rootful:

```
10.88.0.1     host.containers.internal
```

Both of these ip:s represent your host machine.